# Distance between a point and another point that's on a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, arithmetic

I know the formula for finding the shortest distance between a point and a plane, but I was curious of how to find the distance between a given point and *any* point on a particular plane.

Comment: So the distance between two generic points, that is given by the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: The shortest distance will just be the vector from the given point and the point of interest. This is very similar to the shortest point-to-plane distance, we just drop the condition that this vector be orthogonal to the plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pythagorean Theorem. Construct a 90 degree angle with no ends from either side of the angle, like the axis when you look from the first quadrant. [image] In this picture, extend $J$ and $L$ infinitely.

Call your two points on the plane $A$ and $B$.

If you rotate this $90^{\circ}$ angle, so that it fits with your two points $A$ and $B$. Now you have a Right angled triangle ABC. Like this: [image] $c$ now is the line $AB$. Now, do $a^2+b^2=c^2$. But you need to find the values of $a$ and $b$.

Let's say that $A = (x,y)$ and $B = (x_1,y_1)$. $a= y_1 - y$ and $b = x_1 - x$

Now, by rearranging

## $a^2+b^2=c^2$

, you get $\sqrt{a^2+b^2} = c$ This is the formula needed.

## Example:

You have the points $A \quad (1,2)$ and $B\quad (4,6)$. Find the distance between $A$ and $B$.

If you find $a$, you get the difference in the y-axis which $= 6-2=4$ and if you fun $b$, the difference in the x-axis, you get $4-1=3$

Now, recall the rearranged Pythagorean Theorem: $$\sqrt{a^2+b^2} = c$$

And substitute $a$ and $b$ in:

$\sqrt{4^2+3^2} = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} = \sqrt {25} =5 $

So the distance between the two points is 5 (units).